# Concise way to highlight label when items in dropdown changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I want to highlight labels with a color when the associated dropdown value changes.

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <select id="first_dd" data-bind="value: first">
            <option>cat</option>
            <option>dog</option>
            <option>squirrel</option>
            <option>birds</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <label id="first_lb">
            soft</label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <select id="second_dd" data-bind="value: second">
            <option>lion</option>
            <option>elephant</option>
            <option>kangaroo</option>
            <option>buffalo</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <label id="second_lb">
            dangerous</label>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want to change the color of the `first_lb` when the `first_dd` items changed by the user.

How could I accomplish this in JavaScript/jQuery with less code?

Any suggestions highly appreciated.

Comment: Just curious. Your HTML seem's to use `Knockout.js`? If true, then why do you mix KO and jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here goes "less code".
Add change event handler to the `select`.

Try this:

```
$("#first_dd").change(function(){
   $("#first_lb").css('color',"yellow");
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CAa5a/)**

**EDIT:**

As your question asked only for `first_dd` and `first_lb` so I added code only for that part. To apply this to all `select`s use jquery `.each()`.

If, you adding elements dynamically then you must use `on` to bind `events`, else it is enough to use `.change()`.

So as you mentioned your requirements, do this:

```
$('select').each(function(){         //for each select elements in document
    $(this).on('change',function(){  //bind change event
        var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('dd','lb'); //get id for label
        $("#"+id).css("color","yellow"); //highlight
    })
})
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CAa5a/1/)**

Comment: Exactly... thanx for improving the answer.

Comment: @j809: Your code works great. Just have a couple questions. The change event didn't work for me but Click event did. When I placed the change event inside the $(function(){ $("#first_dd").change(function(){
   $("#first_lb").css('color',"yellow");
});}), the change event changed the color when the page loaded, which makes sense. But the click event worked fine only when I clicked the dropdown. Have any idea? Also, should I then write multiple change/click events for each dd/lb or could it be improvised better?

Comment: Actually, `change` event is fired upon change in value of `select` which is appropriate event here. But `click` event is fired on clicking that bound element only. So, I would say go with the change event. So, I will update my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of **for** attribute to connect labels with related **select** dom elements like

```
<select id="first_dd" data-bind="value: first">
    <option>cat</option>
    <option>dog</option>
    <option>squirrel</option>
    <option>birds</option>
</select>
<label for="first_dd">soft</label>
```

Add JS to detect Change and add class

```
$('select').each(function(){
    $(this).on('change',function(){
        $('label[for="'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]').addClass('changed')
    })
})
```

And add appropriate CSS for changed class

```
.changed {
   color: #000;
}
```

Comment: @David Thomas thanks for pointing it out.. i was about to edit it